# AES: Changing plaintext to state

Tags: aes

Can someone explain this to me? 
For example how M chanes to 0c?

Changing plaintext to state:

[image]

Comment: that is a terrible example, "M" is not represented by 0x0c in any standard encoding

Comment: that's what i'm saying! I took this picture from a pdf that explains AES alghorithm.

Comment: If this is not right so in general how text changes to state?

Comment: that is only good at showing where in the state the plaintext bytes are placed, it treats the input as a stream that is placed in the columns top to bottom, left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with AES; instead, it has to do with an encoding that someone picked for this example (and the fact that you have questions about it indicates that it wasn't a great choice by whoever came up with the example).

The encoding is simple; we translate the letters 'A' through 'Z' to the integers 0 to 25, which is in hexidecimal the values 00 through 1A.

M is the 12th letter after A, and hence it is translated into the integer 12, which is 0C in hex.

Comment: Thanks it was so helpful. One more question:Is this method (translate letters to integers as you mentioned) apply in all encryption algorithms?

Comment: @hamedb71: just about all modern encryption systems handle strings of bytes (or, more generally, a string of bits); whoever uses it is expected to translate his message (in whatever format it is in) into a string of bytes.  This translation from 'A'-'Z' -> 0-25 is one possible translation, however it is not the most common.  The most common would be to take the ASCII (or Unicode) values, and reinterpret those as a string of bytes.